# Finding pulse period for output compare on ATmega128 (10-bit fast PWM)

Tags: atmega

Ok, so I have ATmega128 board. I have clock of 16MHz with a prescaler of 8 (2MHz). I am using fast 10-bit PWM to generate a waveform with a top value of 1023.

Given a number, the value put in OCR1A = pulse_period *(number/100). 
The wave will be high for pulse_period * (number/100) and low until it reaches TOP, where the timer will reset.

However, given the information I have (which I gave in first few lines), how do you find the pulse_period when top is 1023?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\${1024 \over ({16MHz\over 8})} = 512\mu s\$

Comment: Hmm I did end up calculating 0.512ms but was unsure what you end up doing with it because I needed pulse_period in clock cycles. But is it as simple as TOP being my pulse period? I tried asking my professor and he was kind of ambiguous and said to calculate it but to me, there doesn't seem like much to calculate...

Comment: If you want to calculate it in terms of CPU cycles then you just need to take the full count and multiply it by the prescaler, i.e. \$1024 \times 8 = 8192\$ cycles.

Comment: I see, so with a clock of 16MHz with a prescaler of 8 and top value of 1023, It will take 8192 cycles to reach top, which will be the value of TCNT3 (counter 3)?

Comment: It will take 8184 cycles to reach TOP, and 8 more cycles for it to reset back to BOTTOM.